# Css & Html, Whats the css for a div id inside div id

Tags: css

Trying to put a div id inside another div id, but having problems.  The html is simple enough, a div inside a div with two closing divs beside each other, but I can't for the life of me get the css correct.  I feel really silly asking such a newbie question, please help.  I want the css to display the html with the outer container with a background color that shows around the outside of the inner container.

Can you give me an example of the css required for this? Thanks for your help, -Matthew

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far? It's easier to help you when we can see the code you're trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

if your html looks like this (this is how i understood your description):

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    some content here
  </div>
</div>
```

your css should look like this:

```
#outer{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
}
#inner{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: From how I understood the question, you probably want either some `padding` on `#outer`, or `margin` on `#inner`. And you have `id="outer"` twice.

Comment: you need to change the second id to inner and add some kind of margin to #inner or a padding to #outer and specify a width.

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem is in my declaration of the ids I listed almost every css property I found in the text book, so something must be conflicting

Comment: Tim, do I really need a width specified?

Comment: Sorry, I listed all four padding directions and must have screwed that up, I See Red now!!! thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Here you have example on JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JXUeF/1/